# What is the sequence of badly approximable numbers to omit in Hurwitz' second Theorem for Diophantine Approximation to obtain better constants?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation, continued-fractions

The well known result of Hurwitz on Diophantine approximation says that for any irrational $\alpha$ there are infinitely many integer numbers $p$ and $q$ such that
$$
|\alpha -\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2}.
$$

If we omit the worst approximable number, the golden ratio $\varphi$, and all its equivalent numbers (in short numbers which are more or less the golden ratio), we are able to improve this inequality to

$$
|\alpha -\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}q^2}.
$$

Then if we also omit $\sqrt{2}$ in the same way now, we can improve the inequality another time. There is a formula for the constants you get on the right side of the inequality by using the so-called Markov Numbers. The sequence of constants you obtain are called Lagrange Numbers.

But my interest lies in the sequence of numbers you have to omit to improve this inequality. In other words how does the sequence $(\varphi,\sqrt{2}, \ldots )$ continue?
Yet another formulation: What is the sequence of the worst approximable numbers going from the worst to less bad?

Comment: done in detail in Cusick and Flahive  , The Markoff and Lagrange Spectra. Related http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Illinois_2003.pdf

Comment: Wasn't it Markov's research?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "equivalent numbers of $a \in \mathbb{R}$", you mean those which are the image of $a$ under an integer möbius transformation. (basically everything you can get when allowing multiplication and addition with rationals and also multiplicative inversion). 
One can prove, that these transformations change the *continued fraction expansion*  of $a$ only on a finite number of positions. Thus, it seems natural to continue the sequence ($\phi, \sqrt{2}, \dots $) in the following way:
$[1;1,1,1, \dots] = \phi$ 
$[2;2,2,2, \dots] = 1+\sqrt{2}$ 
$[3;3,3,3, \dots] = \frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ 
$\dots$ 
$[n;n,n,n, \dots] = \frac{n+\sqrt{n^2 +4}}{2}$ 
$\dots$ , 
in other words, in the $n$-th step omit those numbers of which the *continued fraction expansion* is eventually $n$. However, this strategy is not exhaustive and does not even include all badly approximable numbers.
Another way is to exclude those (badly approximable) numbers, that have a *continued fraction expansion* bounded by $n$. With this, one can keep improving the above inequality
such that 
$
| \alpha- \frac{p}{q} | <\frac{1}{q^2\sqrt{n^2+4}}
$